# DROP TABLE IF EXISTS/CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS not working with SparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark, hive, datanucleus

I am connecting with Hive using Spark 2.x and I am running following Spark Query:

```
spark.sql("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS db_name.table_name""")
spark.sql("""Create TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db_name.table_name""")
```

if the table doesn't exist then the first query gives exception of Table Does not exist.
If Table exist and I am running the second query in the first place then it throws Table already exists exception.

Which Means the condition IF EXISTS and IF NOT EXISTS is not working.

I read it somewhere that there may be data nucleus dependency issue. so Below are the dependencies I am using for Data nucleus:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-rdbms</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Define what DataNucleus has to do with this. You quote some SQL statements, and so are you executing them through DataNucleus for some reason?

Comment: I figured out a way of not using these conditions. But still these are not working

Comment: And it apparently has nothing to do with DataNucleus, as per what the question asked.

Comment: Okay then what can be the possible cause for this?

Comment: I simply asked you to clarify where "DataNucleus" is in this, and you didn't. I could have answered a specific question on DataNucleus. I dont use "Spark", or "Hive" or any of the other stuff here.

Comment: What is your RDBMS ? If you use mysql or sql server or something else this would influence the answer